# I want to know basic rules of chess

Tags: rules

I want to play chess online with friends, and I am new to this community. As such want to know basics of kings, queens, rooks, bishops, knights, and pawns move and play, along with other rules, because I am going to develop chess application for android.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SM2fcenx7KU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The international chess federation has published the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018) which give the rules for playing chess.

"Article 2: The initial position of the pieces on the chessboard" would be a good place to start, followed by "Article 3: The moves of the pieces"

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

There are many resources online, but one good start might be the beginner's course on Lichess: https://lichess.org/learn

Lichess is free software and free of charge.